# I need to put some non-formated text in the X11 clipboard, how can I do this?

Tags: c, linux, clipboard, x11

I think it goes like this:

```
assert(dpy = XOpenDisplay(0));
Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
XSelectInput(dpy, win, PropertyChangeMask);
```

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [c - How to copy to clipboard with X11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868734/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-with-x11)? "I don't know what to do next" is a bit broad. Read the available documentation, then come back with a narrower question?

Comment: I don't know what to do next to put the text on the clipboard.

Comment: You need to read more documentation than can fit in an answer here.

Comment: I did and also read the xclip code, but it seems too complicated. The app needs to stay up and running listening to apps that need the data apparently. I ended up forking xclip from inside my app and giving it the text (through a pipe). With this I have the advantage of not having X11 code inside my app.